# How to call webservice in swift using Almofire?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm fresher for swift language.Can anyone explain how to call service & store in nsmutableArray or nsmutableDictionary like we do in Objective-c Language .

Comment: Hi did you check almofire github webpage? there is all explain well how to working with almofire. please i suggest to do some RND related issue before asking question. so you knowlage going to be increase more

Comment: You're starting on the wrong foot. Do *not* use NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary: use Swift arrays and dictionaries. Do *not* try to replicate the Objective-C way of doing things. This is Swift: use Swift, *à la Swift.* :)

Comment: thanks for giving right direction ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this sample code

Declare array

```
var textArr = [String]()
var nameArr = [String]()
```

Use alamofire in swift3

```
      Alamofire.request(url, parameters: ["user":"any username"
            ,"media_id":"anyid"]).responseJSON { response in

                if response.result.isSuccess == true
                {
                    if let value = response.result.value {
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        print(self.json)

                       let comment_arr = self.json["comment_arr"]
                       for (index, _): (String, JSON) in comment_arr {
                                let i : Int = Int(index)!

                                let name = comment_arr[i]["user"].stringValue
                                let text = comment_arr[i]["text"].stringValue

                                self.nameArr.append(name)
                                self.textArr.append(text)
                            }
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            self.loadingNotification.hide(animated: true)
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                }
        }
```

i hope it's useful for you!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 2.0**

Retrieving posts using API, parsing it, store in array and update UI using `Almofire`.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", parameters: nil)
.responseJSON { response in
    print(response.request)  // original URL request
    print(response.response) // URL response

    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

    let json = JSON(data: response.data!)

    print(json[0]["title"])

    switch response.result
    {
    case .Success:

        let jsonResponse = JSON(data: response.data!)

        if jsonResponse.count > 0
        {                          
            self.arrPosts.addObjectsFromArray(jsonResponse.arrayObject!)
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            // *** Update your UI/UX here ***
        }        

    case .Failure:
        print(response.debugDescription)
    }
}
```